# How to implement a "background" or concurrent thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, concurrent.futures

Figured it out, i think? Runs as expected. I'm not able to view the original code so I wrote this new one up. Is there a better way to do this?

```
import time
import threading

def threadee():
    f = open(r'log.txt')
    for line in f:
        print(line)
    time.sleep(0.2)

def threader():
    while True:
        threadee()
def main():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=threader)
    thread.start()
    while True:
        print('main thread running')
        print(threading.enumerate())
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What have you tried with threads? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Indentation aside, your code looks good in principle. What error or misbehavior do you get?